Porque mis modales Editar y Crear actuan como si fueran uno mismo
Estoy haciendo un crud con modales en laravel, hata ahora llevo el de crear registro, pero nose porque al agregar el de edicion por alguna razon los modales de registro y edicion actuan como si fueran uno solo, osea si hago algo mal en uno en el error me muestra en el otro formulario tambien, y ya no funciona el formulario de registro, como es la primera vez que uso modales nose donde se habra generado ese error, esta es mi modal de registro :


<div class="modal fade" id="RegistroModalP" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header tw-bg-slate-900">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5 tw-font-bold tw-text-white" id="ModalLabelR">Nuevo Proveedor</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="registroForm" action="{{ route('proveedores.store') }}" method="POST">
          @csrf
          <div class="row">
            <div class="mb-3 col">
              <label for="empresa" class="form-label">Empresa o Razon Social:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empresa" name="Razon_Social" placeholder="Nombre de la Empresa">
              @error('Razon_Social')
              <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
              @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 col">
              <label for="representante" class="form-label">RUC:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="representante" name="RUC" placeholder="Representante">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="mb-3 col">
              <label for="correo" class="form-label">Correo Electrónico:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" name="Email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
              @error('Email')
              <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
              @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 col">
              <label for="telefono" class="form-label">Teléfono:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="Telefono" placeholder="Teléfono">
              @error('Telefono')
              <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
              @enderror
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" id="btnRegistro" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



el de mi modal rde edicion:


<div class="modal fade" id="EditarModalP{{ $proveedor->id }}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header tw-bg-slate-900">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5 tw-font-bold tw-text-white" id="ModalLabelE">Editar Proveedor</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="EditForm" action="{{route('proveedores.update', $proveedor->id)}}" method="POST">
          @csrf
          @method('PUT')
          <div class="row">
            <div class="mb-3 col">
              <label for="empresa" class="form-label">Empresa o Razon Social:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empresa" name="Razon_Social" placeholder="Nombre de la Empresa" value="{{ $proveedor->Razon_Social }}">
              @error('Razon_Social')
              <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
              @enderror
            </div>
          
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="mb-3 col">
              <label for="correo" class="form-label">Correo Electrónico:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" name="Email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" value="{{ $proveedor->Email }}">
              @error('Email')
              <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
              @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 col">
              <label for="telefono" class="form-label">Teléfono:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="Telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" value="{{ $proveedor->Telefono }}">
              @error('Telefono')
              <div class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
              @enderror
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" id="btnEdicion" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar Cambios</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



el de mi controlador:


namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Proveedor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProveedoresController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $proveedores = Proveedor::all();
        return view('Proveedores.IndexProv', compact('proveedores'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'Razon_Social' => 'required|string|max:20|unique:proveedores',
            'RUC' => 'required|integer|max:11',
            'Email' => 'required|string|email|max:30', // Validación de correo electrónico
            'Telefono' => 'required|string|min:5|max:11', // Validación de teléfono
    ], [
        'Email.email' => 'El correo electrónico debe ser válido.',
        'Telefono.required' => 'El teléfono es obligatorio.',
        'Telefono.min' => 'El teléfono debe tener al menos :min dígitos.',
        'Telefono.max' => 'El teléfono no puede tener más de :max dígitos.',
    ]);

        Proveedor::create($validated);

        return redirect()->route('Proveedores.Index')->with('success', 'Proveedor creado exitosamente.');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $proveedor = Proveedor::findOrFail($id);
        return view('Proveedores.DetallesP', compact('proveedor'));
    }
    
    
    
}



mi vista donde estan los botones q despliegan los modales:


@section('content')

        @include('Proveedores.RegistrarP')
        @include('Proveedores.EliminarP')
        @include('Proveedores.DetallesP')
        @include('Reportes')
<div class="tw-mx-4">
    <div class="search-area">
        <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Buscar</label>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="mb-3 col" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm tw-w-4/4" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 col">
            <button class="btn btn-success" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#RegistroModalP" type="button"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>Nuevo Proveedor</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive-sm">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered border border-black">
        <thead class="table-primary">
            <tr>
                <th>Cod</th>
                <th>Razon Social</th>
                <th>Ruc</th>
                <th>Correo</th>
                <th>Telefono</th>
                <th style="width: auto;">Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-group-divider">
            @foreach($proveedores as $proveedor)
            @include('Proveedores.EditarP', ['proveedor' => $proveedor])
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">{{ $proveedor->id }}</th>
                    <td>{{ $proveedor->Razon_Social }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $proveedor->RUC}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $proveedor->Email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $proveedor->Telefono }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditarModalP{{ $proveedor->id }}">Editar</button>

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EliminacionModalP" onclick="deleteProveedor({{ $proveedor->id }})">Eliminar</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach       
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>   
@endsection



y las rutas si es que sirve:


Route::get('/proveedores', [ProveedoresController::class, 'index'])->name('Proveedores.Index');
Route::post('/proveedores/store', [ProveedoresController::class, 'store'])->name('proveedores.store');
Route::get('/proveedores/{id}', [ProveedoresController::class, 'show'])->name('proveedores.show');
Route::put('/proveedores/{id}', [ProveedoresController::class, 'update'])->name('proveedores.update');
Route::delete('/proveedores/{id}', [ProveedoresController::class, 'destroy'])->name('proveedores.destroy');



